# regression - bounded depdent variable - model choice

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, modeling, betareg

I am working on a problem where i want to see if a measure (test) is a good predictor of the outcome variable (performance). Performance is a bounded variable between 0-100. I am only thinking of the methodology for now and not working with the data yet.

I am aware that there are different models and  methods that deal with bounded dependent variables, but from my understanding these are useful if one is interested in predictions?

I am interested in how much variance of the dependent variable (performance)is explained by my measure (test). I am not interested in predicting specific outcomes.

**Is it OK to just use normal regression?** 
**Do i need to account for the bounded dependent variable somehow?**

Answer (score 0):

You can scale your dependent variable in the [0, 1] interval and run a logistic regression, that shrinks every input value into that range.

If you can, you can use **fractional logit** models, typically used to predict continuous outputs in the [0, 1] interval.

Alternatively, if you are into Machine Learning, you can implement a **Neural Network regressor** with one output note with a sigmoid activation function.